# TinyMCE Advances is removing blanks (" ")

Tags: tinymce, editor, plugin-tinymce

I want to keep blanks " " inserted by the user in Wordpress with the TinyMCE Advanced plugin. He keeps them only if there are some letters at the beginning. E.g.

```
Fr     09:00 - 18:00
```

But he don't keep them if I use something like this

```
Mo-FR  09:00 - 18:00
       09:00 - 18:00
```

What can I do against this?

**My solution: **
I went away from this structure. Now I use

`Mo-Fr

09:00 - 18:00`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

- Use a real table: `<table><tr><td>` and so on.
- Use pre-formatted text: `<pre>text</pre>`
- Switch to the HTML editor and enter HTML entities or numerical references for preserved white-space: `&#160;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The text is already in a table and adding another table I think is not possible (except I have multiple rows and merge that rows). Hmmm, are there other easier possibilities for the backend user? For me its not a problem but the user ...

Comment: If the tables are rather long, the user could manage them in Excel or whatever and use a template with HTML in it. You can find some templates in an old article I have written [here](http://toscho.de/2009/html-tabellen-erstellen-und-verwalten/).